# Polynomial $f(x_1, …, x_n, y_1, …, y_m)$?

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

In [publication](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677487900137) abstract we have:

> Given a polynomial $f(x_1, …, x_n, y_1, …, y_m)$ with integer coefficients ...

What is the meaning of this polynomial?

This can be: $x_1^{y_1} + x_2^{y_2} + x_2^{y_2} = x_3^{y_3}$ ($n=3$ and $m=3$)?

Answer (score 1):

It would be of the form $\sum a_{i_{1},..,i_{n},j_{1},...,j_{m}}x_{1}^{i_{1}}...x_{n}^{i_{n}}y_{1}^{j_{1}}...y_{m}^{j_{m}}$ where each of the coefficients $a_{i_{1},...,i_{n},j_{1},...,j_{m}}$ are integers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I do not understand completely the meaning of this writing. Are you sure? Maybe it is: $\sum a_{i_{1},..,i_{n}}x_{1}^{i_{1}}...x_{n}^{i_{n}} = 
\sum a_{j_{1},...,j_{m}}y_{1}^{j_{1}}...y_{m}^{j_{m}}$?

Comment: @Aurelio no you need something that is a polynomial in both the $x$'s and the $y$'s  what you've written is the statement that some polynomial in the $x$'s is equal to some polynomial in the $y$'s

Comment: @Aurelio I think, somehow, you have got the wrong idea about [polynomials in several variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring). The expression you wrote in the question is not a polynomial.